# How to manage exoplayer with java in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, exoplayer

I am searching Exoplayer using with ViewPager in java but can not find the full tutorial.

I have issue for stopping and pausing exoplayer while swiping another video.
Is there any tutorial please suggest me.

Adapter.java

```
        package com.daasuu.gpuvideoandroid.Adapter;
    
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
    import com.daasuu.gpuvideoandroid.Activity.OtherUser.OtherUserProfileActivity;
    import com.daasuu.gpuvideoandroid.Model.MainVideoDataModel;
    import com.daasuu.gpuvideoandroid.R;
    import com.daasuu.gpuvideoandroid.Utils.VideoCache;
    import com.daasuu.gpuvideoandroid.databinding.ItemMainVideoBinding;
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayer;
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.MediaItem;
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.Player;
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.SimpleExoPlayer;
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ProgressiveMediaSource;
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView;
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.StyledPlayerView;
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource;
    import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.cache.CacheDataSource;
    
    import java.util.List;
    
    public class MainVideoAdapter2 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MainVideoAdapter2.MyViewHolder> {
        private Context context;
        private List<MainVideoDataModel> data;
        private boolean likeFlag = false;
        private boolean followFlag = false;
        private boolean isPlaying = false;
        ExoPlayer exoplayer;
        StyledPlayerView styledPlayerView;
    
        public MainVideoAdapter2(Context context, List<MainVideoDataModel> data) {
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
        }
    
        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            ItemMainVideoBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), R.layout.item_main_video, parent, false);
            return new MyViewHolder(binding);
        }
    
        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(MainVideoAdapter2.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
            MainVideoDataModel model = data.get(position);
            holder.setExoplayerStyled(model.getVideo_url());
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return data.size();
        }
    
        public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
            private ItemMainVideoBinding binding;
    
            public MyViewHolder(ItemMainVideoBinding binding) {
                super(binding.getRoot());
                this.binding = binding;
    
                binding.imageUserMainVideo.setOnClickListener(this);
                binding.videoView.setOnClickListener(this);
            }
    
            //        styled exoplayer with cache
            void setExoplayerStyled(String video_url){
                binding.progressCircular.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                exoplayer = new ExoPlayer.Builder(context).build();
                styledPlayerView = binding.videoStyledPlayerView;
                styledPlayerView.hideController();
                styledPlayerView.setUseController(false);
    
                ProgressiveMediaSource mediaSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(
                        new CacheDataSource.Factory()
                                .setCache(VideoCache.getInstance2(context))
                                .setUpstreamDataSourceFactory(new DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory()
                                        .setUserAgent("rgcache"))
                                .setFlags(CacheDataSource.FLAG_IGNORE_CACHE_ON_ERROR)
                ).createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(video_url));
    
                exoplayer.seekTo(0);
                exoplayer.prepare();
                exoplayer.pause();
    
                styledPlayerView.setPlayer(exoplayer);
                exoplayer.setPlayWhenReady(false);
    
                binding.videoStyledPlayerView.addOnAttachStateChangeListener(new View.OnAttachStateChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onViewAttachedToWindow(View view) {
                        styledPlayerView.setKeepScreenOn(true);
                        exoplayer.addMediaSource(mediaSource);
                        exoplayer.prepare();
                        exoplayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
                        exoplayer.setRepeatMode(exoplayer.REPEAT_MODE_ONE);
    
                        if(binding.videoStyledPlayerView.getPlayer() != null) {
                            binding.videoStyledPlayerView.getPlayer().play();
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(View view) {
                        binding.videoStyledPlayerView.getPlayer().stop();
                        binding.videoStyledPlayerView.getPlayer().clearMediaItems();
                        exoplayer.seekTo(0);
                        exoplayer.setPlayWhenReady(false);
                        exoplayer.stop();
                        if(binding.videoStyledPlayerView.getPlayer() != null) {
                            binding.videoStyledPlayerView.getPlayer().pause();
                        }
                    }
                });
    
                //buffering
                exoplayer.addListener(new Player.Listener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onIsLoadingChanged(boolean isLoading) {
                        Player.Listener.super.onIsLoadingChanged(isLoading);
    //                    Log.e("onIsLoadingChanged", String.valueOf(isLoading));
                    }
    
                    @Override
                    public void onPlaybackStateChanged(int playbackState) {
                        Player.Listener.super.onPlaybackStateChanged(playbackState);
                        Log.e("onPlaybackStateChanged", String.valueOf(playbackState));
                        binding.imgVideoStop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        if (playbackState == 3){
                            binding.progressCircular.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }
    
                    @Override
                    public void onPlayWhenReadyChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int reason) {
                        Player.Listener.super.onPlayWhenReadyChanged(playWhenReady, reason);
                    }
                });
    
    //            touch listener play & pause
                binding.videoStyledPlayerView.getVideoSurfaceView().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        if (isPlaying == false){
                            binding.imgVideoStop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            isPlaying = true;
                            exoplayer.setPlayWhenReady(false);
    
                        }else{
                            binding.imgVideoStop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            isPlaying = false;
                            styledPlayerView.setKeepScreenOn(true);
                            styledPlayerView.setPlayer(exoplayer);
                            exoplayer.addMediaSource(mediaSource);
                            exoplayer.prepare();
                            exoplayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
                            exoplayer.setRepeatMode(exoplayer.REPEAT_MODE_ONE);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
    
            //on click event
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (v == binding.imageUserMainVideo) {
                    context.startActivity(new Intent(context, OtherUserProfileActivity.class));
                }
                if (v == binding.videoView) {
                    Log.e("isPlaying = " , String.valueOf(isPlaying));
                    if (isPlaying) {
                        binding.videoView.pause();
    //                    binding.imgVideoStop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        isPlaying = false;
                    } else {
                        binding.videoView.start();
    //                    binding.imgVideoStop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        isPlaying = true;
                    }
                }
    
            }
    
    
        }
    }
```

item.xml

```
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.StyledPlayerView
        android:id="@+id/videoStyledPlayerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:animation_enabled="true"/>
```

**Issues**:

- After a specific position, it plays previous videos when swipe to next video.
- Plays multiple videos on swipe
- On swipe back(previous videos) don't stops previous video.
- How to stop when to redirect another activity.

Please suggest the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **addOnPageChangeListener** for getting the user interaction for the view pager. add this code snippet in the onCreate method.In my project ,I handle it like this ::

```
  binding!!.mediaViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(object : OnPageChangeListener {

                override fun onPageScrolled(
                    position: Int,
                    positionOffset: Float,
                    positionOffsetPixels: Int
                ) {
                    if (exoPlayer.isPlaying) {

                        exoPlayer.pause()


                    }

                }

                override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
                  
                        if (exoPlayer.isPlaying) {
                            exoPlayer.pause()
                        }
                       

                    

                }

                override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {
                  

                    exoPlayer.pause()
                   

                }
            })
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. First of all please suggest in Java. Second thing the Exoplayer instance is used in adapter class, so how to access that in activity or fragment. In above code the exoplayer instance is used in ViewPager which is in Activity or fragment.

Comment: Please provide your existing code of fragment/activity adapter and viewHolder class .it will be easier to get the solution. Thanks